# SQL Query: Combine multiple rows into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

SQL Server 2016

I am trying to query a set of Event Registration data and get all, by date, items on the same line for an individual record.

I have a listing of individuals with name and ID plus an event code and event title and date as you see below.

| ID | Name | EventDate | ProductCode | ProductName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Jayson | 2/1/2021 | PROD1 | Class 1 |
| 123 | Jayson | 2/1/2021 | PROD2 | Class 2 |

What I want as an end result is

| ID | Name | EventDate | ProductCode1 | ProductName1 | ProductCode2 | ProductName2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Jayson | 2/1/2021 | PROD1 | Class 1 | PROD2 | Class 2 |

This needs to be grouped by ID and date so I can pull a report, by date, of all the products an individual has on that date purchased by them and this needs to be expandable because some people have 1 purchase while others have 5 purchases.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please show us your attempt. And clarify how many possible product codes and names do you need to handle? You probably want [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Well, therein lies the problem, I am not even sure how to do this.  I found some code online that shows me how to create a single column with all records using a delimiter separator between the events but I need separate columns for each.  As far as possible product codes needed?  Probably up to 20 per date but this is an open spot as this is by event and it depends on how many breakout sessions an event has for registrations to be made against.

Comment: This is a job for SSRS, Crystal Reports, or Excel or something like that, especially if your requirement is that 'this needs to be expandable'.

Comment: Ok, perfect.  The idea is to throw this into SSRS.  If that is the case, should I use the code I found that does a delimiter and then let SSRS parse it out to columns?

Comment: No, use a matrix is SSRS where it will do the work for you. Just pull the rows in your query.

Comment: Is the order of the result columns significant? If so, what defines it.

Comment: What will you do for the one who has 100 purchases? 200 columns?

Comment: Order is not significant as long as it is grouped by date to show only those products purchased on said date.

Yes, if someone has 100 items purchased, it will be 200 rows. 

So, for SSRS, I get the idea of a matrix and I am relatively new to SSRS so I am still learning.  I have pulled the raw SQL code into an SSRS report and placed it in a matrix.  This is grouping very well on date and name BUT I get a new row in the group for each product purchased.  How do I get those to go from rows to columns?

Comment: Ok, I figured out how the matrix in SSRS works, or at least I think I have.  I now get a grid, grouped by date and showing only the products purchased on the same row - YAY!  Only problem I am coming across now is that SSRS is creating a column for each individual product item available and just filling the cell if that product was purchased.  If not, the cell is left blank.  So, if alphabetical, if I have 26 products for each letter of the alphabet, I get 26 columns and if someone purchases A and Z only, I get A, 24 blank columns, and then Z.  Can that gap be closed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.ProductCode, b.ProductName from table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON (a.ID=b.ID)
```